# Trying to update Bugzilla on Fedora 16 using YUM

Tags: linux, yum

I am currently running Bugzilla version 4.0.6 and would like to update to 4.2.

I have tried `yum check-update` and `yum update bugzilla` but it is not updating.

Am I doing something wrong?  If not, is there a way to force the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can see is bugzilla 4.2 seems not to be available on fedora's repositories, so yum won't be able to find it. You might have to do a new manual installation or look for a 3rd party repository with bugzilla 4.2 already packaged.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Is there a way to tell when it is included in the repositories besides running update as trial and error?

Comment: I'm not really sure, you might need to write an script or something for checking and notice you. IMO if package mantainer don't see a reason for upgrading it (i.e. losing vendor support for that version) and not being the latest Fedora release, it might not happen.